# Horizontally Align content under title with multiple lines

Tags: css

My titles may be one line or multiple lines.

I'm trying to align the content under the title to the top without have to specify a height for the title.

If I use margin-bottom on the title, the content aligns to the bottom.

Adding min-height to the title gets the result I need but if the title breaks to more lines, the min-height breaks it.

In the image below, I am trying to get the text to align to the top of the red line.

[image]

```css
.flexbox-row {
    display: flex;
}

.columns .section-title {
    margin-bottom: auto; /* ADDED */
}


.columns .item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
    max-width: 33.333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.333333%;
    padding: 0px 45px;
}

.columns .item:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.columns .item:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

#buy-sell .columns p {
    padding-right: 110px;
}
```

```html
<section id="" class="columns">
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="flexbox-row item-wrapper">
            <div class="item">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    Title 1
                </h2>                        
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh.
                </p>
            </div> 
            <div class="item">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    Title 2 Title 2 Title 2 Title 2
                </h2>                        
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh.
                </p>
            </div> 
            <div class="item">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    Title 3 Title 3 Title 3 Title 3 Title 3
                </h2>                        
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh.
                </p>
            </div>                                                             
        </div>              
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The suggested answer align the content to the bottom of the container. I am trying to align the content to the top but under the title.

Comment: Oh, my bad, It seemed to work because the texts in the snippet have the same size

Comment: @Junky can you past a picture of what you are trying to do? Your post is being closed for lack of clarty.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added an image to show where I am trying to get the text to align.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting you titles in a different row than your content. For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <h1>title</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

This way the content will stick to the top of each row. You'll need to use some flex stuff to make it work the way you want it though. Something like this should work:

```
.row {
  flex-direction: 'row';
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: '40px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing anything of the original code all you need to do is force the `margin-bottom` to a size you need. Fortunately a simple `margin-bottom: auto` will do the trick:

```css
.columns .section-title {
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

The snippet...

```css
.flexbox-row {
    display: flex;
}

.columns .section-title {
    margin-bottom: auto; /* ADDED */
}

.columns .item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
    max-width: 33.333333%;
    flex-basis: 33.333333%;
    padding: 0px 45px;
}

.columns .item:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.columns .item:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

#buy-sell .columns p {
    padding-right: 110px;
}
```

```html
<section id="" class="columns">
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="flexbox-row item-wrapper">
            <div class="item">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    Title 1
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    Title 2 Title 2 Title 2 Title 2
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <h2 class="section-title">
                    Title 3 Title 3 Title 3 Title 3 Title 3
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis elit nec magna placerat pharetra non vitae nibh.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This solution would work if all three content blocks had the same number of lines but does not work when the content is more or less. I've updated my code sample.